OkHttp first call to execute method returns unreadable characters
On first call
▼♦

??{"value":[]}??☺??B?@D


All subsequent calls are processed correctly
{"value":[]}

Request code
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(DEFICIT_STATEMENTS_LIST_URL
                        + "/items?$filter=OData__Status eq 'test1' or OData__Status eq 'test2'")
                .header("Accept", "application/json;odata=nometadata;streaming=true;charset=utf-8")
                .build();

String responseString = "";
ResponseBody responseBody = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute().body();
responseString = responseBody.string();

The response comes from SharePoint
In Postman it works correctly right away

What happens when you leave that charset out?

@g00se same result
